# Facebook function does not return user when using getUser()

Tags: php, codeigniter, facebook

I am using the Facebook files to login to an app I have created just so people can login through Facebook on the site I am working on. I am working in **Code Igniter** and I was able to return the users info and everything. I had it working no problem.

But when I went on to the developer side because I wanted to test it locally and changed the site url I got an error about something I can't remember I think the error code was 191 I could be wrong.

I then figured ok well that didn't work so I changed it back and now I am unable to retrieve any of the user data when logging in. There is no errors being thrown. The functions from the Facebook file work fine but I can't seem to get the user info again.

I have a model that I use to grab the info from login.

```
class Facebook_model extends CI_Model {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    $config = array(
        'appId'  => 'XXXX',
        'secret' => 'XXXXX',
        'fileUpload' => true
    );

    $this->load->library('facebook', $config);

    $user = $this->facebook->getUser();


    $profile = null;

    if($user)
    {
        try {
            // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
            $profile = $this->facebook->api('/me?fields=id,name,link,email');
        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            error_log($e);
            $user = null;

        }
    }

    $login_params = array(
        'redirect_uri' => (base_url() . 'test'),
        'scope'        => 'email'
    );

    $fb_data = array(
                    'me' => $profile,
                    'uid' => $user,
                    'loginUrl' => $this->facebook->getLoginUrl($login_params),
                    'logoutUrl' => $this->facebook->getLogoutUrl()
                );



    $this->session->set_userdata('fb_data', $fb_data);
}
}
```

So right after the `($user = $this->facebook->getUser();)` I did a test and echoed `$user` and got **0**. Where before I didn't.

The one change I made was in the `$login_params` var. I changed the **redirect_uri** to **localhost** which did not work for obvious reasons and then I changed it back to what I have displayed now.

Thanks

Comment: This is super frustrating. I literally cannot see anything wrong with the code. I checked the debugger on facebook and I am getting no errors.

Answer (score 0):

getUser only returns the user info if the user is logged in your application/web (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getUser/)

So you should deal in the model with the posibility that the user is not logged in (is 0) and show him the login buttom. Besides you should reset the session info in case the user is 0.